# How to solve occasional Apache Camel failures when reading from IBM MQ?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I have **Apache Camel** based simple POC app trying to pull messages from **IBM MQ** and post it to **Apache kafka**. I see the log file is continuously rolling with the below exception. I did some search on this issue with not much help.

I also found a fix was made in Apache NiFi project for the same issue. Not sure if the same fix needs to be applied in Apache Camel/Kafka project as well. Here is the JIRA URL.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4976

The camel version used - 2.21.1

Here is the complete stacktrace,

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCMQ1049: The character set '1208(UTF-8) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63' cannot convert some or all of the string '[B@b1beb88'
An attempt was made to send or receive string data using a character set not capable of translating the strings content.
Only encode a message using a character set known to be appropriate for the string data being transmitted..
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.extractBodyFromJms(JmsBinding.java:172)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.createBody(JmsMessage.java:221)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaProducer.createRecorder(KafkaProducer.java:172)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaProducer.process(KafkaProducer.java:259)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectBlockingProducer.process(DirectBlockingProducer.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:113)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:721)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:681)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCMQ1049: The character set '1208(UTF-8) Unmappable Action: REPORT Unmappable Replacement: 63' cannot convert some or all of the string '[B@b1beb88'
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor75.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQUtils.computeTextFromBytes(WMQUtils.java:382)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQUtils.computeTextFromByteBuffer(WMQUtils.java:421)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.messages.WMQTextMessage.getText(WMQTextMessage.java:240)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTextMessageImpl.getText(JmsTextMessageImpl.java:205)
    at com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage.getText(JMSTextMessage.java:124)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.extractBodyFromJms(JmsBinding.java:157)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:816)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage.bytesToString(JmqiCodepage.java:745)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQUtils.computeTextFromBytes(WMQUtils.java:375)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```